# I cannot get the device.uuid in the second page of Iphone Phonegap

Tags: cordova, device, uuid

I have create a phonegap project in xcode.

At the first page index.html, I add the code to get the device.uuid in the onDeviceReady(), and print it out as alert. Then I add a form and submit/pass it to next page in the project. The second page I still remain the device.uuid code printing code, but the alert code does not show up.

Then I try to remove the device.uuid, only print out a alert message, the message show up correctly.

So I want to ask, why the second page does not work? It looks like only device function does not working. Basically I just dump the first page content in the second page, the first page work correctly, but the second page does not...

Comment: can you post some code, it would be easier to resolve

Comment: I found that is because I use data-transition="slide". The new page is  loaded in ajax method, so it does not launch the onDeviceReady() in the new page.